# Can I build a string using sql server case statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to do something like this in SQL server 2008:

```
CASE WHEN var1 = 1 THEN 'message 1 ' END as messages
CASE WHEN var2 = 1 THEN 'message 2 ' END as messages
```

Where messages would result in `message 1 message 2` if both variables were true.

I do realize I can do a subquery and create the messages, but I was curious as to whether it could be done without a subquery or `with` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by concatenating the strings and using an empty string when there is no content.

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN @var1 = 1 THEN 'message 1 ' ELSE '' END +
  CASE WHEN @var2 = 1 THEN 'message 2 ' ELSE '' END as messages
```

Comment: I didn't expect it to be that simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you have concatenate strings:

```
CONCAT(
  CASE WHEN var1 = 1 THEN 'message 1 ' END,
  CASE WHEN var2 = 1 THEN 'message 2 ' END
) as messages
```